# Error while processing route: index undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to create a utility class for our ember app. I'm using Ember CLI for building the app. The problem is that apparently you cannot create a util class, only a function class ? Any ideas or explanations on this matter ?

**app/utils/cookie-manager.js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var CookieManager = Ember.Object.extend({

getCookie: function(cname)
{
    //
},

setCookie: function(cname, cvalue, exdays)
{
    //
},

clearCookie: function(cname)
{
        //
}
});

export default CookieManager;
```

**app/routes/index.js:**

```
    import Ember from 'ember';
import CookieManager from '../utils/cookie-manager';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    renderTemplate: function(){
        if (CookieManager.getCookie("user-token") === "")
        {
            this.render('index');
        }
    },

    model: function() {
        if ((CookieManager.getCookie("user-token") !== "")))
        {
            //
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by a “util class” vs a “function class”.

Comment: Should've explained better, my bad. I mean in the docs the example contains a single function inside the util file, instead of a class containing multiple functions.

Comment: You can export whatever you want and use it elsewhere in your application. Alternately, you could use [ember-cli-cookie](https://github.com/achambers/ember-cli-cookie) and inject cookie access as a service.

Comment: I need to export an entire object instead of a function. And apparently it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are creating an object definition with the `.extend` and you are not creating an instance via create. I would look at using `ember-cli` and the service blueprint to create a cookie service (`ember generate service cookie-manager`)